# How to style an add to cart <button> with CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, styling

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bq39gt6/1/) Example of what I need above.

Hey guys, I'm having some issues finding a solution to this small problem.  I have an add to cart button and I'm looking to style it similar to many other buttons I have on a website I'm working on.  I want the effects to work and of course to remove the basic visuals that adding `<button>` will automatically have.  There were some similar topics to this nature, but I was unable to find a solution based on their suggestions.

```css
.main_btn_m {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #2f5289;
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: .7s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.main_btn_m span {
  float: left;
}
.main_btn_m:hover {
  background: #2c3339;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: .7s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hvr-underline-from-left_m {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hvr-underline-from-left_m:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FEC55A;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-underline-from-left_m:hover:before,
.hvr-underline-from-left_m:focus:before,
.hvr-underline-from-left_m:active:before {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
 <a class="main_btn_m hvr-underline-from-left_m" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()" style="width: 250px; float: left; margin-bottom: 50px;">basic btn that works </a> 

<!-- bottom btn is what I am trying to accomplish, an add to cart btn that works with the right styling -->
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()" style="">
  <a class="main_btn_m hvr-underline-from-left_m" style="width: 250px; float: left;">add to cart 
        <!-- need to get rid of styling while keeping the same style as 'basic btn that works' --></a>
</button>

<!-- original working code 
        <button class="form-button btn-pro addcart_view" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()"> 
        </button>  -------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: The animation code is in your jsfiddle

Comment: Fix your HTML first. You can't have a link inside a button. https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No instead oof applying the `class` attribute to the link inside the button, apply it to the button itself

```html
<a class="main_btn_m hvr-underline-from-left_m" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()" 
style="width: 250px; float: left; margin-bottom: 50px;">basic btn that works

</a>

<!-- bottom btn is what I am trying to accomplish, an add to cart btn that works with the right styling -->
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()" class="main_btn_m hvr-underline-from-left_m" style="width: 250px; float: left;">
<a>add to cart                      <!-- need to get rid of styling while keeping the same style as 'basic btn that works' -->              
</a>

</button>


<!-- original working code 
<button class="form-button btn-pro addcart_view" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()"> 
</button>   
-------------------------------------------->

<style>

.main_btn_m {
    float          : right;
    display        : block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background     : #2f5289;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    transition: .7s;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.main_btn_m span {
    float: left; 
}

.main_btn_m:hover {
    background: #2c3339;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: .7s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hvr-underline-from-left_m {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hvr-underline-from-left_m:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FEC55A;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-underline-from-left_m:hover:before, .hvr-underline-from-left_m:focus:before, .hvr-underline-from-left_m:active:before {
  right: 0;
}
</style>
```

Try this code that ive fixed here

Comment: Thanks Sibusiso, this works.  I had to add some CSS for anyone wondering

CSS
.main_btn_m a {
 color: #eeeeee;
}

.main_btn_m a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}

But you've practically got me to the finish line.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the **ADD TO CART** link is wrapped in a `button` element. Simply add this button style to your CSS and it should work.

```
button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Obviously you may need a more specific selector depending on your overall CSS.

It is worth mentioning as @Quentin stated this isn't valid HTML5 structure. As stated in the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

**Permitted content** [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) which is defined as:

> Phrasing content defines the text and the mark-up it contains. Runs of
>   phrasing content make up paragraphs.

Comment: I had the right structure before Corporalis, but it wasn't working.  Either under the right structure, the styling was off or I fixed the styling with poor structure with the button not actually working.  I was at an impasse, and the code above was used to highlight exactly what I was looking for.  I read Quentin's post but unlike your post and Sibusiso's, it wasn't helpful or anything I didn't already know.  I attempted Sibusiso's answer and with minor mods, it worked perfectly.  However, I believe your alternate solution using background: transparent; will also work.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a class="main_btn_m hvr-underline-from-left_m" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()" 
style="width: 250px; float: left; margin-bottom: 50px;">basic btn that works

</a>

<!-- bottom btn is what I am trying to accomplish, an add to cart btn that works with the right styling -->
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()" class="main_btn_m hvr-underline-from-left_m" style="width: 250px; float: left;">
<a>add to cart                      <!-- need to get rid of styling while keeping the same style as 'basic btn that works' -->              
</a>

</button>


<!-- original working code 
<button class="form-button btn-pro addcart_view" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()"> 
</button>   
-------------------------------------------->

<style>

.main_btn_m {
    float          : right;
    display        : block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background     : #2f5289;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    transition: .7s;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.main_btn_m span {
    float: left; 
}

.main_btn_m:hover {
    background: #2c3339;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: .7s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hvr-underline-from-left_m {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hvr-underline-from-left_m:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FEC55A;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-underline-from-left_m:hover:before, .hvr-underline-from-left_m:focus:before, .hvr-underline-from-left_m:active:before {
  right: 0;
}
</style>
```